# Reg. Custom Basic Authentication in WCF

Tags: wcf, basic-authentication

I'm using custom basic authentication module (http://www.custombasicauth.codeplex.com) for authenticating users in WCF service. I've used a custom membership provider and in the ValidateUser method I've making a db call and returning true if the authentication succeeds. I also created a binding that uses transport security for the WCF service. Everything works fine now the problem is the client want two endpoints to be created for the WCF service and the custom basic authentication should happen for one endpoint not for the other.

Is it really possible to achieve this by using the custom authentication module or I have to try some other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible when hosting your service in IIS. IIS has authentication scoped per whole virtual directory and your endpoints are exposed on the same service = single resource in single virtual directory. You must either move to self hosting and host service in windows service (you will not need that module anymore) or you must deploy the service again to different virtual directory or web application and change security configuration in each deployment separately (= every endpoint will be in separate deployed service).